# installing flask and flask mysqldb problem

Tags: python, pip

i was trying to install flask but i got this problem every time
**any one could help me please !**

```
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/91/bdfe808fb5dc99a5f65833b370818161b77ef6d1e19b488e4c146ab615aa/mysqlclient-1.3.0.tar.gz#sha256=06eb5664e3738b283ea2262ee60ed83192e898f019cc7ff251f4d05a564ab3b7 (from https://pypi.org/simple/mysqlclient/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting flask_mysqldb
  Using cached Flask-MySQLdb-0.1.1.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
ERROR: Cannot install flask-mysqldb==0.1.1 and flask-mysqldb==0.2.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    flask-mysqldb 0.2.0 depends on mysqlclient
    flask-mysqldb 0.1.1 depends on mysqlclient

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: Show us the installation command and describe your environment!

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your install command? This seems odd: `flask-mysqldb==0.1.1 and flask-mysqldb==0.2.0`. Need more about the steps you took to reach this state.

Comment: pip3.9 install flask
___________________

pip3.9 install flaskmysql

Comment: any solution for a clean installation i have python 3.9 , 3.8 and 3.6 installed